# Raytracing normal mapping

Tags: matrix, 3d, texture-mapping, raytracing, normals

I am currently working on a raytracer and I just "bumped" in an issue.
I implemented texture mapping for planes, cylinders and spheres and it's working pretty well... Except for the normal map part.
Here is what I have, the in-world position and the in-world normals of each pixel : [world-space normals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFcHo.png).
And some tangent-space normal map (the usual normal map).

I can't seem to figure out how to convert the tangent-space normals to world-space. I have tried using a "TBN" matrix but the normals are off : [normal map projected normals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ30o.png).

And here is my code to compute the new normal :

```
VEC3    t = vec3_cross(worldnormal, new_vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)); 
VEC3    b;
if (!vec3_length(t))
    t = vec3_cross(worldnormal, new_vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
t = vec3_normalize(t);
b = vec3_normalize((vec3_cross(worldnormal, t)));
VEC3    map_n = vec3_normalize(get_texture_color(normal_map, texcoords));
MAT3    tbn = new_mat3(t, b, worldnormal);
worldnormal = vec3_normalize(mat3_mult_vec3(tbn, map_n));
```

get_texture_color() returns the normal map's texture color divided by 255.f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So !
I just found what was wrong with my normal mapping !
After trying to use a constant {0, 0, 1} normal to see if my TBN matrix was right (and it was) I just found out that normal map's tangent space normals had to be "converted"

So the right code is :

```
VEC3    t = vec3_cross(worldnormal, new_vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)); 
VEC3    b;
if (!vec3_length(t))
    t = vec3_cross(worldnormal, new_vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
t = vec3_normalize(t);
b = vec3_normalize((vec3_cross(worldnormal, t)));
VEC3    map_n = vec3_normalize(get_texture_color(normal_map, texcoords));
//map_n * 2 - 1
map_n = vec3_sub(vec3_scale(map_n, 2), new_vec3(1, 1, 1));
MAT3    tbn = new_mat3(t, b, worldnormal);
worldnormal = vec3_normalize(mat3_mult_vec3(tbn, map_n));
```

So close, yet so far !
Here is how it looks now, looking pretty good IMHO !

[New (propper) normal mapping using TBN matrix !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRn21.jpg)

[With a better material for middle pillar !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1VFp.jpg) (not the other "sort of" water)